# Is "bringing it up" idiomatic in this context?

Tags: expressions, idiomatic-language

Is **bringing it up** idiomatic in this particular context?

A: So when did he let you know he was dating your ex?

B: He didn't really. Not until recently.

A: Didn't you talk to him?

B: I ran into him a few times, but I guess he felt more comfortable not **bringing it up**.

Comment: Yes, that's natural.

Comment: Arguably ***to bring [some subject matter X] up*** tends to imply *steering the conversation towards X*, where X is a topic familiar to all conversants (who may or may not wish to talk about X). But in the cited context it's being used to mean ***presenting new information*** *(...he felt more comfortable **not telling me**)*. Which is "okay", but might lead to misunderstandings in certain contexts.

Comment: It's totally natural speech.  Ignore the above comment about "bringing up..." not being used to talk about new information or causing confusion in that context - it is completely incorrect.  You can absolutely "bring up" new information, and this is one very typical use of the phrase.

Comment: I also think there is a distinction to be made between just mentioning a fact  and consciously or purposely introducing a new subject or a new aspect in a given conversation, which is, I think, what "to bring sth up" means. If I were the person of your example, I would rather  "mention" a detail such as dating B's ex than start a conversation about it.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. It's a perfectly natural usage.

The "alternative" use would be something like, "I guess he felt that bringing it up would be awkward."